# How to join multiple columns with a single column using a single join?

Tags: mysql

I would like to join multiple columns with a single join if this is even possible. I have written my code below which works fine, however I would like to understand if there is a more efficient way of joining using a single left join rather than two of them.

In both of the joins I am joining on the country table

```
SELECT 
w1.country,
a.route_warehouse_id,
w2.country,
a.leg_warehouse_id

FROM new_table a
LEFT JOIN country_table w1
on a.route_warehouse_id = w1.warehouse
LEFT JOIN country_table w2
on a.leg_warehouse_id = w2.warehouse
```

Comment: Since you want in the same row 2 different values of the column country this is the way to do it.

Comment: Not really since you need to reference two different rows in the country_table.

Comment: Yep, that's the right way of doing it, since you are actually joining twice. And if, for example, you had a "final_warehouse_id" then you could join a third time too.